# Uniformization theorem and metrics on Riemann surfaces

Tags: riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I know next to nothing about Riemannian geometry, and have some trouble interpreting some things I read in relation to the uniformization theorem for Riemann surfaces.

To me the uniformization theorem says that the universal cover of any Riemann surfaces is biholomorphic to either $\mathbb{C}P^1$, $\mathbb{C}$ or $D$, the open unit disk with its complex structure given by that induced from $\mathbb{C}$(?).

In particular, for $S$ of genus $g>1$ we have a universal cover $D$, so $$\pi:D\to S$$
Now I do not see what this has to do with a metric of constant negative curvature? $D$ is just an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and so it seems to me that it carries a flat metric? I just don't see where in this story a metric of negative curvature shows up.

Comment: Its well known that the disc $D$ is a model of non-euclidean geometry, "lines" are circles orthogonal to the boundary. This this is probably what is behind whatever you are talking about.

Comment: This is the discovery that Poincare was very proud of: Conformal automorphisms of the unit disk $D$ are precisely the orientation-preserving isometries of the hyperbolic metric on $D$. Can you now conclude that every Riemannian metric on $S$ is conformal to a hyperbolic metric?

Comment: @MoisheCohen Using that theorem I can proof that the metric on $D$ descents to $S$, so $S$ carries a constant $-1$ curvature metric. How do I show that this metric is in the same conformal class defined by the complex structure though?

Comment: @MoisheCohen Essentially I do not see how to relate the hyperbolic metric on $D$ to the conformal structure on $S$?

Comment: Do you know how to show that the hyperbolic metric on the unit disk is conformal to the Euclidean metric on this disk?

Comment: @MoisheCohen Ah, that would precisely solve my question. I thought that that sounded weird so I didn't try to prove that, but given that this is true I can complete the proof easily. To be sure: $D\to S$ being a covering implies that the conformal structure of $D$ (the Euclidean one) is the pull back of the conformal structure of $S$ (the one induced by the complex structure). Then since the Euclidean metric is conformal to the hyperbolic metric, your previous remark shows that this conformal map is an isometry, and hence the hyperbolic metric lands in the correct conformal class?

Comment: That's right. Now, try to prove conformality of the two metrics: This is really easy!

Comment: @MoisheCohen Taking a closer look at the definition of the metric, this follows immediately from the fact that the hyperbolic metric is simply a rescaling by a factor $\frac{2}{1-|z|^2}$ of the standard Euclidean metric, correct?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thanks a lot for your help. I had a difficult time finding a good source explaining how all of this works exactly, but it is clear now.