# Invariant lifts of a closed curve on a surface of genus > 1.

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, geometric-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

I am learning some things about surfaces of genus greater than $1$, and I am trying to answer this question :

Let $S$ be a compact and orientable surface of genus $g \geq 2$, and $c$ a closed curve on $S$. Let $\widehat{S}$ denote the universal covering space of $S$. Given a deck transformation $\widehat{f}: \widehat{S} \rightarrow \widehat{S}$, is it true that there exists only a finite number of lifts $\widehat{c}$ of $c$ to $\widehat{S}$ that are $\widehat{f}-$invariant ?

(by "lift", I mean the image of a  map $\widehat{c} : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \widehat{S}$ that lifts the application $c : \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow S$ defining the closed curve $c$).

I hope this is clear ! Thank you for any help :)

EDIT :

My attempts to answer that question : suppose that there exists a lift $\widehat{c}$ of $c$ which is $\widehat{f}-$invariant. Given another deck transformation $\widehat{g} : \widehat{S} \rightarrow \widehat{S}$, I would like to prove that the lift $\widehat{g}(\widehat{c})$ of $c$ is $\widehat{f}-$invariant if and only if $\widehat{g}$ and $\widehat{f}$ commute. It seems to be natural but I don't know how to prove that properly...

Any idea ?...

Comment: Yes, your intuition about $f$ and $g$ is correct. One way to prove this is to use hyperbolic geometry as Max suggested. Then use the fact that the centralizer of $f$ is a finite index extension of $<f>$ (unless $f=e$ of course).

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! But how can I write my intuition about $f$ and $g$ properly ? Intuitively, I would like to say the following : if $\widehat{c}$ and $\widehat{g}(\widehat{c})$ correspond to the same geodesic of $\widehat{S}$, then they are homotopic, in the sense that there is a homotopy between $c$ and $c$ such that the path of a basepoint of $c$ under this homotopy is a non-trivial loop. And this seems to be impossible (but why ?) Is that true ? Thanks again !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to know that your surface $S$ admits a hyperbolic structure, i.e. is homeomorphic to the quotient $H^2/\Gamma$ of the hyperbolic plane $H^2$ by a group of isometries $\Gamma$ acting properly discontinuously and freely on $H^2$. See e.g. my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373526/prove-that-closed-orientable-riemann-surfaces-are-hyperbolic-pecicely-when-their), although if you do not fix a conformal structure in advance, constructing a hyperbolic structure is easier, see for instance, [here](http://verso.mat.uam.es/~javier.aramayona/hypstr.pdf). In the same lectures by Aramayona you will find all the needed background material for what is written below.

Every oriented homotopically nontrivial loop $\alpha$ on $S$ represents a (unique up to conjugation) element $\gamma\in\Gamma$. The latter acts on $H^2$ as a **hyperbolic isometry**: It has exactly two fixed points on the boundary circle $S^1$ of $H^2$. The loop $\alpha$ admits a lift $\tilde{\alpha}$ which is invariant under $\gamma$. The lift $\tilde{\alpha}$ has exactly two limit points in the boundary circle $S^1$: These are the fixed points of $\gamma$. I will use the notation $Fix(\gamma)$ for the fixed-point set of $\gamma$ in $S^1$.

Conversely, if $\gamma$ preserves a (not necessarily simple) parameterized arc $\tilde\beta\subset H^2$, then the limit (accumulation) points of $\tilde\beta$ in $S^1$ are exactly the two fixed points of $\gamma$. Therefore, for each $\gamma'\in \Gamma$, if $\gamma'(\tilde\alpha)$ is $\gamma$-invariant, then $\gamma'$ preserves the fixed-point set $Fix(\gamma)\subset S^1$: It either fixes $Fix(\gamma)$ pointwise or swaps the two fixed points. The latter cannot happen since $\Gamma$ is torsion-free.

**Lemma.** The stabilizer $\Delta$ of $Fix(\gamma)=\{x_1, x_2\}$ in $\Gamma$ is an infinite cyclic group.

**Proof.**  Let $L\subset H^2$ be the hyperbolic geodesic with the limit points $x_1, x_2$. Since there is a unique such geodesic, the line $L$ has to be invariant 
 under $\Delta$. Therefore, $\Delta$ acts freely as a properly discontinuous  group of isometries of $L\cong {\mathbb R}$. The isometry group of ${\mathbb R}$ is the semidirect product of ${\mathbb R}$ (acting via translations) and ${\mathbb Z}_2$ (whose generator is the reflection $t\mapsto -t$). I will leave it to you as an exercise to show that every discrete infinite subgroup of ${\mathbb R}$ is isomorphic to ${\mathbb Z}$. Hence, $\Delta$ is isomorphic to ${\mathbb Z}$. qed

Therefore, every element $\gamma'\in \Gamma$ which sends $\tilde\alpha$ to a $\gamma$-invariant arc, belongs to the cyclic group $\Delta$. The latter contains $\langle \gamma\rangle$ as a finite index subgroup (since $\gamma\ne 1$). Therefore, the preimage of $\alpha$ in $H^2$ contains only finitely many $\gamma$-invariant arcs.

Comment: Thank you very much for this precise answer ! I think I have to learn a little bit of hyperbolic geometry, but this is clearer now. Thanks !